# Validate number with multiple points

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove a version number for a string that has multiple dots, for instance ***app-9.6.0*** should return ***9.6.0*** and ***app-960*** should return **None**. I tried with the code bellow but it returns numbers without the dots either.

```
import re
re.findall(r'[\.\d]+', 'app-960')
```

How can I implement a parser or regex for this case?

Comment: Are the periods randomly placed or is there always a pattern that you can rely on?

Comment: There is no pattern. They are a version number so can be 1.0, 1.1.0, 1.10.0, 1.1.1.0 and so on.

Comment: Most version schemes are `a.b.c.d`  and potentially any sub-variation.  If that's true in your case, you technically do have a pattern.  Is it possible for `1.2.3.4.5.6` to occur?

Comment: How about `(?<=[^0-9.]+)((?:[0-9]\.)+[0-9]+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match `app-` and digits with 1 or more dots in between, you can use a capture group.

Start the capture with matching digits and then repeat 1 or more times matching a hyphen and again 1 or more digits.

**Example**

```
import re

pattern = r'app-(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)'
s = 'app-1 app-9.6.0, app-1.0, app-1.1.0, app-1.10.0, app-1.1.1.0'

print (re.findall(pattern, s))
```

**Output**

```
['9.6.0', '1.0', '1.1.0', '1.10.0', '1.1.1.0']
```

---

A broader variant matching 1+ non whitespace chars with `\S+` before the hyphen:

```
pattern = r'\S+-(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
str_for_search = 'app-9.6.0'
search = re.search(r'\w+-(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', str_for_search)
if search:
    version = search.group(1)
else:
    version = None
print(version)
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not enough general out of current data.  
 I try it with "thisIsMyApp-123456.0" and it returns None. Should be 123456.0

Answer (score 1):

is it always 2 dots?

if so you can do this

```py
import re
re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', 'app-960')
re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', 'app-9.6.0')
```

if no dots is ok then what you got already works

if you want atleast 1 dot you can do:

```py
re.findall(r'\d\.[\.\d]+', 'app-9.6.0')
```

edit:

you can do this to avoid the multiple dots in a row problem:

```py
import re
re.findall(r'\d(?:\.\d)+', 'app-9.6.0 app=9..9 app1.1.1.1.1.1 app1')
```

Comment: This will also match `1..2....3`.

Answer (score 1):

If `app-` is always going to be a consistent string, it's probably going to be faster and easier to do this without a regex:

```py
def version_number(full_version):
    version_num = full_version.replace("app-", "", 1)
    # If I'm interpreting your question right, you also
    # want to validate that the version contains at least one dot
    if "." in version_num:
        return version_num
    else:
        return None
```

If you need to do this with a regex for some reason, others have given examples that should work.

Answer (score 1):

To be more general and avoid to be sticked to "app-" , i suggest this old way of programming with a simple algorithm:
As long as the end of the string is made of numbers or point, collect it.
At the end, check if a point. That's all.

```
def old_geek(someString):
version = ""
pointFound = False
# read in reverse order
for i in range(len(someString)-1,-1,-1):
    c = someString[i]
    if not c in ".0123456789":
        break
    version = c + version
    pointFound = pointFound or (c == '.')
if not pointFound: 
   version = None
return version
```

I test it against the regexp of 555Russich which is not sticked to app- (but has still some default with thisIsMyApp ):

```
print("------ old geek -----")
for test in tests:
    print(test,' :',old_geek(test))

print("------- 555 Rushich")
for test in tests:
    print(test,' :',reg1(test))

------ old geek -----
app-9.6.0  : 9.6.0
app-960  : None
thisIsMyApp-123456.0  : 123456.0
appli.bat-200.0.1  : 200.0.1
app-1.1.1.1.1.0  : 1.1.1.1.1.0
------- 555 Rushich
app-9.6.0  : 9.6.0
app-960  : None
thisIsMyApp-123456.0  : None
appli.bat-200.0.1  : 200.0.1
app-1.1.1.1.1.0  : 1.1.1
```

A question i asked me : what's the performance between old way of programming and regexp ?

```
    loop : 10000
check_oldGeek --- 0.03163409233093262 seconds 
loop : 100000
check_oldGeek --- 0.31208014488220215 seconds 
loop : 1000000
check_oldGeek --- 3.101634979248047 seconds 
loop : 10000
reg1 --- 0.03866410255432129 seconds 
loop : 100000
reg1 --- 0.3761019706726074 seconds 
loop : 1000000
reg1 --- 3.765758991241455 seconds
```

old geek wins : 3.10s against 3.76s ... for 1 million loops . not too much.

Hope you enjoy as i do :)